# Flutter Align widget does not align

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a ListItem and I want the text to be in a cardview that takes up the entire width and just enough height as the text size is. This is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Card(
                child: Text(
                  'some text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

There are two widgets inside the stack, I want the second widget to lap above the first widget but just for a small part. Yet as you can see, the align of the second widget isn't at the bottom but at the top. I also tried switching Container and Align as child of each other but to no avail. Here's a screenshot of the resulting code

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like "BottomCenter" (with capital B). You should use `Alignment.bottomCenter`. But you probably need to set alignment for `Stack`.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
    ),
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      child: Card(
        child: Text(
          'some text',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: the uppercase B whas sort of a typo. the code does use a smaller b